# Loading fontenc T1 removes emphasis from journal titles in references

Tags: font-encodings, italic, apacite

I have to work with APA standards (I am using apacite) and write text in Spanish (need á é í ó ú). For some reason, if I use

```
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
```

not even typing `\'a` will get me an `á`, but I get italics in the journal titles in the references.

Instead, by using

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

I get the accents to work however I type them, but italics dissapear from my references.
I am working with a template from a journal and I believe that loading many packages is creating issues across them.

I guess it must be some extra package I am not aware of.

This is a MWE

```
\documentclass[colTwo]{IIR}
\begin{document}
\titlerunning{The Article}
\authorrunning{SNOW}
\doiThis{10.15446/ing.investig.xxxx}
\title{Title}
\subtitle{Title in Spanish} 
\author{Jhon Snow\affilnum{1}}

\begin{abstracts}
\begin{abstract}
    a e i o u
\keywords{[song].}
\end{abstract}

\begin{abstract}[spanish]
    á é í ó ú
\palwords{[canción].}
\end{abstract}
\end{abstracts}

\maketitle

This is a cite \cite{Deanfield1980}.

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

[This is the class](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnWb-NVACgJ1sUVroaD2JJ7Gr2IS?e=6XeRyo) and [this is the bib file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnWb-NVACgJ1sUY6ZkfImcrpSSgJ?e=it1AXA)

Thank you.

EDIT:
I notice the warning

```
Font shape `U/lasy/m/n' in size <9.03> not available(Font) size <9> substituted
```

I used 
`\usepackage{lmodern}`
and the problem was solved. Apparently, my accentuated characters were being replaced by regular ones in the process of adjusting the font size.

Comment: The class uses the `epigrafica` font, which is not available in T1 encoding *and* has wrong definitions for the accented letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class uses the `epigrafica` font, which is not available in T1 encoding. It also has a weird way to redefine accents.

Here's a fix for the accented Spanish letters.

```latex
\PassOptionsToPackage{draft}{graphicx}
\documentclass[colTwo]{IIR}

\DeclareTextComposite{\'}{OT1}{A}{"C1}
\DeclareTextComposite{\'}{OT1}{E}{"C9}
\DeclareTextComposite{\'}{OT1}{I}{"CD}
\DeclareTextComposite{\'}{OT1}{O}{"D3}
\DeclareTextComposite{\'}{OT1}{U}{"DA}
\DeclareTextComposite{\'}{OT1}{a}{"E1}
\DeclareTextComposite{\'}{OT1}{e}{"E9}
\DeclareTextComposite{\'}{OT1}{i}{"ED}
\DeclareTextComposite{\'}{OT1}{\i}{"ED}
\DeclareTextComposite{\'}{OT1}{o}{"F3}
\DeclareTextComposite{\'}{OT1}{u}{"FA}
\DeclareTextComposite{\~}{OT1}{N}{"D1}
\DeclareTextComposite{\~}{OT1}{n}{"F1}

\begin{document}
\titlerunning{The Article}
\authorrunning{SNOW}
\doiThis{10.15446/ing.investig.xxxx}
\title{Title}
\subtitle{Title in Spanish} 
\author{John Snow\affilnum{1}}

\begin{abstracts}
\begin{abstract}
    a e i o u
\keywords{[song].}
\end{abstract}

\begin{abstract}[spanish]
    á é í ó ú ñ Á É Í Ó Ú Ñ
\palwords{[canción].}
\end{abstract}
\end{abstracts}

\maketitle

This is a cite \cite{Deanfield1980}.

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Notes: the first line ensures no error for the missing `logo` picture, remove it in the production version. I changed `references.bib` into `\jobname.bib` just not to clobber my files.

[image]